# Can't delete a row using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

The problem that I'm having is that I can't delete a row when using entity. I'm able to find the row, but the error I get the next error:

> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I tried updating the database in the package manager console, I tried several different ways of deleting the record, but no luck by the moment. Auto Migrations are enabled.

Below is the code I am currently trying to use.

```
   var ctx = new Context();
   ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = myUsername };
   ctx.Users.Attach(user);
   ctx.Users.Remove(user);
   ctx.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
   ctx.SaveChanges();
```

All help is appreciated. I have been banging my head on this for hours.

Comment: Is `UserName` a primary key of `ApplicationUser` entity?

Comment: @Dennis It is not. The primary is Id. Which is a uuid.

Comment: it is seem to be you have an optimistic concurrency exception do you know what is that? do u have rowversion coulmn or you reading and writing from mutliple DbContexts at the same time?

Comment: @BassamAlugili I dont believe that I have a rowversion column. It is is possible that I have multiple dbcontexts going though. I am unsure how to check.

Comment: This might to be a side effect. I have found this info:
"
I ran into this and it was caused by the entity's ID (key) field not being set. Thus when the context went to save the data, it could not find an ID = 0. Be sure to place a break point in your update statement and verify that the entity's ID has been set."

Comment: check your Id at this time point with the debbuger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to remove entity in EF is the following:

- locate entity using `DbSet<T>`. This could be retrieving entity from set or attaching it to the set;
- call `DbSet<T>.Remove`;
- call `DbContext.SaveChanges`.

Since `ApplicationUser.UserName` is not a primary key property, you need to find entity. Attaching doesn't make sense here - `DbSet<T>.Attach` tells context to treat entity with given primary key as existing and non-modified, but you don't set primary key value (probably, it is generated in constructor, since you're using GUIDs?).

Something like this:

```
// assuming, that user names are not unique
var user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.UserName == myUsername);
if (user != null)
{
    ctx.Users.Remove(user);
    cts.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: this worked 100%. thank you. I appreciate the logic as well. Had it been a primary key could I have just attached it?

Comment: @alphamalle: if your code will set primary key property to some existing value, it will delete entity from database after attaching and calling `Remove`.

Answer (score 0):

You remove your entity and after that mark it as a modified. Remove line:

```
ctx.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
   var ctx = new Context();
   ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = myUsername };
   ctx.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted
   ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Or just remove line about modifing record. It is not needed, cause first of all You are deleting it not change. And second of all, .Remove function already set it to proper state.

Comment: Maybe there is no record actually that matches UserName = myUsername ? Debug your code. Check myUsername variable value and make sure the record with UserName = myUsername exist in database.

Comment: @I was able to confirm that it is successfully finding a matching record. I can see all properties of the object.

Comment: But this function is not finding a record in database: ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = myUsername }; . It is creating something that looks like Your record. Did You look in Your database for that record?

Comment: Correct I can see the record in the database, and when debugging.

Comment: Dennis was correct. Thank you very much for taking time out to help.

Answer (score -1):

```
  var ctx = new Context();
  ApplicationUser user =ctx.ApplicationUser.Where(c=>c.UserName == myUsername).FirstOrDefualt()
```

You need to fetch the whole  record. Otherwise, you need to fill all the `Not Null` columns

Comment: And that's exactly what the accepted answer does.